# Is it possible to bind to a regular DOM element using KeyMap

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

What I have tried:

```
    new Ext.util.KeyMap({
        target: 'search',
        eventName: 'itemkeydown',
        binding: [
            {
                key: Ext.EventObject.ESC,
                scope: this,
                fn: function() {
                    console.log('esc');
                },
                defaultEventAction: 'preventDefault'
            }
        ]
    });
```

where `search` is the `id` of the element. Though it doesn't bind to the element - I pass focus to it, press `ESCAPE` and callback isn't fired.

What have I missed?

PS: I also tried `Ext.get('search')` instead of `search` with the same results.

PPS: `search` element is not an ExtJS control, it is regular `<input type="text" ...>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my working code:

```
var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
    target: 'search',
    eventName: 'keydown', // changed from itemkeydown -> keydown
    binding: [{
            key: Ext.EventObject.ESC,
            scope: this,
            fn: function() {
                console.log('esc');
            },
            defaultEventAction: 'preventDefault'
        }
    ]
});
```

My HTML element is as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="search"/>
```

`keydown` seems to be the default value for `eventName`. The code will work without it. You could also get it working by using the 4.0 style:

```
var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap("search", {
    key: Ext.EventObject.ESC,
    handler: function() {
        console.log('esc');
    },
    scope: this,
    defaultEventAction: 'preventDefault'
});
```

Comment: Right, I should have understood that myself that `itemkeydown` is a custom extjs event http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-itemkeydown Thanks PS: will check you tomorrow at work after trying that :-)